# Pandas for loop not updating rows correctly with iloc?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to write a script that will iterate through a df based on column duplicates ("Emails") and update the information from the older row to the most recent row (column = "Created On"). Some data in the most recent row is NaN, so this data needs to be updated by older row, when that row is not NaN. My dataset is very large and has many columns. I have sorted the list in the correct order as so:

```
crm_dupes_s = dupes_df.sort_values(["Email", "Created On"], ascending=False)
crm_dupes_s.head(25)
```

Then made sure NaN values are being read correctly:

```
crm_dupes_nan = crm_dupes_s.replace('nan', np.NaN)
crm_dupes_nan.isna()

  Full Name First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Status   Email   Created On 
0 False     False       True        True        False    False   False
1 False     False       True        False       False    False   False
```

Listed columns for later loop iteration, but took out email as those values are not being updated:

```
cols_to_change = list(crm_dupes_nan.columns)
cols_to_change.remove('Email')
cols_to_change

[' Full Name',
 'First Name',
 'Middle Name',
 'Last Name',
 'Status',
 'Created On']
```

Finally here is my for loop:

```
#Iterates through all rows

for i in range(0, crm_dupes_nan.shape[0]):

#If there is a value for Email

    if not pd.isna(crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, :]['Email']): 

#If the row Email values are the same "duplicates" then execute cell value change

        if crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, :]['Email'] == crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i, :]['Email']:  
            for col in cols_to_change:
                if not pd.isna(crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, :][col]):
                    crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, :][col] = crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i, :][col]
```

I know the first 3 lines are correctly recognizing duplicates, but the "iloc" functions are not changing the NaN values?? I have tried "iat", "set_value", "replace", and "where" and have gotten various issues with all of them. I was under the impression "iloc" was the preferred method for task and performance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
Full Name   First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Status  Email   Account Numbers Primary Account Number  Business Phone  Home Phone
0   Zac Daniels  Zac    NaN   Hopkins  Active   zdaniels@gmail.com   NaN            3452432.0    NaN    NaN
1   Zac Daniels  Zac    NaN   Hopkins  Active   zdaniels@gmail.com 13254512.0   4564534.0    (949) 803-8033   (817) 817-9177    
2   Zach Fred    Zach   NaN   Wilbern  Active   zFredericks@miami.com 45632532.0    12342313.0   (313) 313-3133   (313) 313-3133
```

Comment: this `crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, :][col]` has the issue of chained indexing. Read here for more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Consider rewriting `crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, crm_dupes_nan.columns.get_indexer(col)]`

Comment: Roger checking...

Comment: Same with the email like... `crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i, crm_dupes_nan.columns.get_indexer(['email'])]`. In general if you see `][` in pandas it is bad.

Comment: With "get_indexer" I get ```TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '(Do Not Modify) Contact' was passed``` and with trying to avoid chain indexing I wrote ```crm_dupes_nan.iloc[:, (i-1)(col)] = crm_dupes_nan.iloc[:, (i)(col)]``` and I get ```TypeError: 'int' object is not callable```

Comment: I feel like your problem can be solved without looping throw the rows and update manually. Can you share your `dupes_df`?

Comment: @QuangHoang is probably correct also. we may be treating a symptom instead of solving the problem.

Comment: I see thank you for the suggestions, I am still getting errors though:                     ```if not pd.isna(crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i, crm_dupes_nan.columns.get_indexer(['Email'])]):```                                 ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Comment: I just shared my df (I can't upload images yet, so sorry for formatting).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to change single values of pandas dataframes, which I suspect is intentional on the part of the developers.  The point of pandas is to efficiently work with tabular data without having to iterate through the rows and columns.  When you subset using `crm_dupes_nan.iloc[i-1, :][col]`, you get variable that is no longer tied to the dataframe, so assigning a value to it won't work.

I'm thinking you might need to look at pd.groupby to gather your email groups, form an updater dataframe with the data you would want filled in, then use pd.merge or maybe pd.update to replace the nan values in crm_dupes with the updater values.  Details left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: I see....thank you! I have tried grouping the data but had trouble separating Email duplicates and merging on values to get rid of NaN's but I guess tryin over and over again is part of the process lol